# Grab username of User from model django

Tags: python, html, django, model, html-injections

Not really sure if there is a duplicate question, probably is but I can't find it

I've got this code here (**models.py**)

```
# Create your models here.
class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):
    # Create relationship (don't inherit from User!)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # Add any additional attributes you want
    can_view_all = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    can_edit_all = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    can_add_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    alias = models.CharField(default='none')

    @property
    def alias(self):
        return models.CharField(default=self.user.username)

    def __str__(self):
        # Built-in attribute of django.contrib.auth.models.User !
        return self.user.username

    @alias.setter
    def alias(self, value):
        self._alias = value
```

As you can see, I'm  trying to  grab the username with the alias property, but it doesn't work, can someone help me, Basically, I'd like to be able to edit the boolean fields later on (I can do that) but I don't know which user I'm editing if there is a way to get the username directly via HTML injection that would be even better, but I just need a way to show which user I'm editing

By the way, it isn't always the same user I'm signed in as, so I can't just use user

Thank you

Edit:
**Views.py**

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class UserUpdateView(UpdateView):
    context_object_name = 'userprofileinfo'
    fields = ('can_view_all', 'can_edit_all', 'can_add_admin')
    model = models.UserProfileInfo
```

Comment: share your views.py where you use UserProfileInfo

Comment: There you go, thanks for your time mate

Answer (score 1):

In Django, to reference a field in a foreign key object, you have to use the double underscore syntax, like this - `user__username`

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering, I want to do a logical operation in my HTML, which says, {% if user.can_edit%} and then do something, this, however, doesn't work, , even if it's true, how can I grab this info?